# @CreateTimestamp, @UpdateTimestamp. Why is the field "create" null for the returned object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 fields: create and update.

```
@CreateTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Timestamp create;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false)
private Timestamp update;
```

After create object: everything is OK. But during doing update object, I get for the returned object the field "create" is null. In DB an object is saving correct with filled fields.
How can it fix?

Full code of class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @CreateTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Timestamp create;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Timestamp update;
}
```

Method update:

```
public UserEntity update(UserEntity user, String id) {
     UserEntity userFromDB = userDao.findById(id);
     UserEntity updatedUser = userDao.save(userFromDB);
     return updatedUser;
}
```

When return updatedUser, field create is null.

Comment: Could I see your code ?

Comment: sovannarith cheav, yes.

Comment: So you mean, when retrieve object from db, the field create is null, right?

Comment: I thinks you should use @CreationTimestamp instead.

Comment: No, when retrieve object from db fields create and update are filled.

Comment: I added method, update.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear where you have imported `@CreateTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` from.

However, as you seem to be using Spring, you could use [`@CreatedDate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/CreatedDate.html) and [`@LastModifiedDate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/LastModifiedDate.html) from Spring Data. And ensure your entity is annotated with `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`.

Apart from it, since Java 8, with the introduction of the new [Date and Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html), you should avoid using [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) and related classes such as [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html). A suitable replacement for [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html), in your situation, would be [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue in the Timestamp conversion back from the values stored in the database.

- If you are not keen on it, i would suggest you to use Date instead of Timestamp in the model Class.
- Since you've not mentioned the schema of your database, you can verify if the column names in model to be same as the ones in the database
- Shouldn't you be using SaveOrUpdate Method or update Method to update in the database
- Use Criteria to fetch the records like below and use restrictions whenever necessary

  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PatientPanel.class);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("datasourceId", dataSourceId));

This thread is similar to : 
[Springboot + MySQL: cannot read any date type from (DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP) MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375551/springboot-mysql-cannot-read-any-date-type-from-date-datetime-timestamp-m)

Comment: In DB also timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp as Anotation and

java.util.Date.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date create;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date update;
}
```